# PDF Cut rectangles with its contain and add to new PDF file IText

Tags: c#

I have a PDF file and several rectangles with its contents, and I want to cut out one rectangle with its contents and add it to a new PDF file. How to do it?

Comment: You need to provide more information on your problem. This is not clear representation of your attempt or problem to your end goal.

Comment: Ok. I have a PDF file(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JwJz_zRz-l8K8DrnFn7LyoasJZ_hWkic/view?usp=sharing) in which need cut a several rectangles with its contents and insert in new PDF file.